# Pause chess game during promotion

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, chess

I'm programming a 2D chess game with Unity 2022.3.7f1.
Now I'm implementing the promotion of a pawn. I've created a Canvas with buttons the player can click to choose the figure the pawn will become.
Now my problem is, that I want to "pause" the game, while the player chooses the figure.
The game should continue after the figure is chosen. The Canvas should disapear and the opponent's turn starts.

I have the following functions where the movement is handled and if there is a promotion.

I call the `MoveFigureClickControll()` with a `OnMouseDown()` function.

```
public void MoveFigureClickControl(Figure figure, Tile tile)
{
    if (figureInHand == false && tile == null)
    {
        activeFigure = figure;
        figureInHand = true;
    }
    else if (figureInHand == true && activeFigure != null && legalMove != null)
    {
        if (legalMove.Contains(tile.Get()))
        {
            if (tile.transform.childCount > 1)
            {
                Object.Destroy(tile.transform.GetChild(1).gameObject);
            }
            activeFigure.transform.SetParent(tile.transform, false);
            activeFigure.GetComponent<Figure>().SetNewPosition();

            if (this.GetComponent<MoveHandler>().Promotion(activeFigure))
            {
                if (activeFigure.figureColor)
                {
                    Promotion_white.gameObject.SetActive(true);
                    inPromotion = true;
                    WaitForPromotion();
                }
                else
                {
                    Promotion_black.gameObject.SetActive(true);
                    inPromotion = true;
                    WaitForPromotion();
                }
            }

            figureInHand = false;
            activeFigure = null;
            ChangePlayer();
        }            
    }
}
```

```
 void OnMouseDown()
{
    GetComponentInParent<Board>().MoveFigureClickControl(this, null);
}
```

`OnMouseDown()` is in my `Figure`-Script. `MoveFigureClickControll()` is in my `Board`-Script as well as the other functions below.

Everything is working fine but not the `WaitForPromotion()`

```
private IEnumerable WaitForPromotion()
{
    while (inPromotion)
    {
        yield return null;
    }
}
```

I have implemented the `RookPromotion()` jet to test everything.

```
public void RookPromotion()
{
    (int, int) pawnPosition = activeFigure.GetCurrentPosition();
    string tileName = gameObject.GetComponent<MoveHandler>().GetTileName(pawnPosition.Item1, pawnPosition.Item2);
    Object.Destroy(gameObject.transform.Find(tileName).transform.GetChild(1).gameObject);
    GameObject newFigure;
    if (activeFigure.figureColor)
    {
        newFigure = Instantiate(rookPrefab_w);
        newFigure.transform.SetParent(gameObject.transform.Find(tileName), false);
        newFigure.GetComponent<Figure>().SetNewPosition();
    }
    else
    {
        newFigure = Instantiate(rookPrefab_b);
        newFigure.transform.SetParent(gameObject.transform.Find(tileName), false);
        newFigure.GetComponent<Figure>().SetNewPosition();
    }
    inPromotion = false;
}
```

I have tried it that `public void MoveFigureClickControl(Figure figure, Tile tile)` was `public IEnumerator MoveFigureClickControl(Figure figure, Tile tile)` with `yield return WaitForPromotion();`. But than I couldn't click a figure.

Answer (score 1):

That's not the correct way to call coroutines unfortunately. You won't be able to use them properly in your current set up.

A quick fix would be to change your main function there to a coroutine too

```
public IEnumerable MoveFigureClickControl(Figure figure, Tile tile)
{ 
    while(true) 
    {
       ... 
       yield return null;
    } 
}
```

then in the part where you call your promotion code, instead call

```
yield return WaitForPromotion();
```

where you call your main function (assuming it's currently called like this)

```
void Update() 
{
    MoveFigureClickControl();
}
```

would instead have to become the super strange looking

```
void Update() 
{
    moveCoroutine ??= MoveFigureClickControl(); // or equivalent 

    moveCoroutine.MoveNext();
}
```

Because this is sort of a weird hacky way to do this I'd instead reccomend looking into a *state machine* to work with this sort of problem.

Comment: I understand.
I do not use Update. MoveFigureClickControl is called, when a mouse click ist done at a figure.
I've changed it to IEnumerable, but then I can't perform a click action

Comment: @0x01010 that would be a very bad idea, the timing is clearly handled elsewhere - at best it would be meaningless and confusing, at worst you could miss move next calls that should occur. null is standard for coroutine yields in this context

Comment: I've done that. But when I change the MoveFigureClickControl() to IEnumerable, I cannot access the function.
What I do. I perform a OnMouseDown() on the figure and with that I call MoveFigureClickControl()

Comment: @Teand if you're tieing this directly into a unity's event callback you'd have to do it differently. I'll edit my answer. Please include all the relavent code in your question if you can.

Comment: My fault. I add this Information to my post. Then everything should be consistent.

Comment: I've added the code and informations. I hope this helps

Comment: I've added all your code now. So far everything is working. The only porblem is, I do not enter the WaitForPromotion().
I have the call with `yield return WaitForPromotion()` but I do not enter it.
I also have a `yield return new WaitForSeconds(10f);` in the WaitForPromotion(), but it does not wait 10 seconds and that's because I do not enter the function

Comment: and I do not see if you have changed your code, as you mentioned two days ago